# Свойства css в зависимости от URL средствами javascript или jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Задача в том, чтобы на сайте в зависимости от URL для `<div id="content">` подменялось свойство стиля.

К примеру, чтобы только на главной странице сайта (ну или же возможно на нескольких страницах) `<div id="content">` имел свойство `padding-right: 200px`, а на всех других имел `padding-right: 0px`

Comment: правите на стороне сервера шаблон главной страницы, добавляя в родительский элемент что нить вида `class="main-page"`, и перекрываете паддинг для `.main-page #content` в стилях. для таких задач js имеет смысл использоваться лишь когда контент грузится динамически, но и тут добавлять надо класс родительского блока, не более.

Comment: вы можете в тег body (или другой блок, родительский для вашего блока) добавлять класс типа каждой страницы (page-article, page-catalog, ....). Так делают многие cms для упрощения стилизации.
и, как написано в сообщении выше, перекрывать типа  .page-catalog #content

Comment: А вы не могли бы  показать пример,как правильно прописывается это все?

Answer (score 0):

Использование JavaScript кода в такой ситуации избыточно. Если это CMS, то проще отредактировать шаблоны страниц и вставить нужные классы для каждой ситуации.
 Если всё же позарез нужно использовать именно вариант с JS, то воспользуйтесь информацией об адресной строке через объект `window.location` и выставляйте стили в зависимости от названия страницы.
[Пример](https://codesandbox.io/embed/9on3v9w41o)